# App crashes because of huge allocations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I have a little game that I want test in Instruments for leaks and allocations, however a couple of seconds in, it crashes on me. I have provided a screenshot. Please take a look. A little information on my app : In my initial scene (which causes the crash) I use `CCVideoPlayer`, `CCSpriteBatchNode`, `CCSpriteFrameCache`.

Here is how I use them:

```
//CCVideoPlayer

    NSUserDefaults *uD = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            if([uD boolForKey:@"videoShown"] == NO){
                [CCVideoPlayer setDelegate:self];
                [CCVideoPlayer playMovieWithFile:@"Main.mp4"];
                [uD setBool:YES forKey:@"videoShown"];
            }
```

and

```
//spriteframecache and batchnode
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sprites.plist"];
            spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"sprites.png"];
```

I do not use schedulers in this class.

http://oi47.tinypic.com/35hmwrb.jpg

Should you require more detailed screenshots of allocations, please tell me which one, I'll upload it. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Instruments _itself_ is crashing?

Comment: no, sorry... the app crashes while being inspected by Instruments. I have edited the title, thanks.

Comment: how many textures do you load? Your app consumes 144 MB memory, that means it's unlikely to run on devices with less than 512 MB total memory.

Comment: well, not even so many... Maybe 15 or so.